# Angular - Bind to formControlName when Scope of ng-template Changes

Tags: angular, templates, data-binding, scope

I have an angular ng-template which correctly assigns an index value to formControlName when the template is within its parent formArray, but fails to do so when moved outside of the array.

The following works:

```
    <div formArrayName="searchLimits" *ngIf="!sectionCollapseState?.searchLimits">

      <!-- template inside array -->

      <ng-template #checkboxSetTemplate let-upper="displayCount" let-sectionName="sectionName">
        <div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1]; let i = index;"
          class="col-md-12">
          <label [ngClass]="this.modelService.getClassMap(item)">
            
            <!-- 'ng-reflect-name' is assigned 'i' in rendered page, as expected -->
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" />
              ...
          </label>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
```

but the following does not:

```
  <div formArrayName="searchLimits" *ngIf="!sectionCollapseState?.searchLimits">
  </div>

  <!-- template outside of array -->

    <ng-template #checkboxSetTemplate let-upper="displayCount" let-sectionName="sectionName">
      <div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1]; let i = index;"
        class="col-md-12">
        <label [ngClass]="this.modelService.getClassMap(item)">
            
          <!-- 'ng-reflect-name' is assigned 'i' in rendered page, as expected -->
          <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" />
            ...
        </label>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

The following directive which is inside the array uses the above template:

```
<div>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="checkboxSetTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{displayCount: SearchLimits?.length,
          sectionName: SearchLimits}">
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

The associated TypeScript:

```
  private buildForm() {
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      refinements: this.formBuilder.group({
        searchLimits: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        keywords: new TextboxControl(null)
      })
    }, this.searchService.formHasUserDataValidator());
  }
```

Can anybody please let me know how I can create a working template outside the scope of the array?

Thank you very much,

Rod

Comment: try use `[formControl]="searchLimits.at(i)"` (if you has a getter searchLimits that return the formArray) or `[formControl]="yourForm.get('searchLimits'+i)"`

Comment: Thank you for your comment Eliseo. I've done as you suggest, but that doesn't work. Actually, the value 'i' is available in my original code, but doesn't get assigned to 'formControl'. A 'Cannot find control with path 'refinements -> 0' is generated when the faulty code executes.

Comment: sorry it's `[formControl]="yourFrom.get('searchLimits.'+i)"` -see the dot at the end of "searchLimits"

Answer (score 0):

Since formControlName is placed outside of parent formGroup it's not working.

**Try this:**

> change [formControlName] ===> [formControl].

```
<!-- template outside of array -->
<ng-template #checkboxSetTemplate let-upper="displayCount" let-sectionName="sectionName">
  <div *ngFor="let item of [0, 1]; let i = index;"
    class="col-md-12">
    <label [ngClass]="this.modelService.getClassMap(item)">
      <!-- 'ng-reflect-name' is not present in rendered page, but is expected -->
      <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="i" />
        ...
    </label>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made that change, but the result is the same. I'll add the Typescript showing the structure to my original post.

Comment: If it possible can you create stackblitz?